# Mongoose query by current date

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have a mongoose collection. This collection have a **day** property in it.

So let's say I have 3 documents in it:

```
{day: "2017-07-16T17:00:00.000Z"}
{day: "2017-07-17T17:00:00.000Z"}
{day: "2017-07-18T17:00:00.000Z"}
```

Each date has hardcoded 17:00 time in it. Consider this as the ***start time***.

So let's say currentDate is 2017.07.17 and it's 16h. I need to return document that has day that is 16th, because of the time. 
Next one starts in an hour, and in an hour I should be returning the 17th.

I tried:

```
Table.find({ day: { $lt: Date.now() } })
```

But this, on the 18th, still returns 16th.

How do I write this query so it returns document that is currently 'active' ?

Comment: It should work `Table.find({ day: { $lt: Date.now() } })`... Your day field is a string?

Comment: It's not string, it's date object, it just gets parsed as ISOString when I pull it out. Also, like I said, that doesn't work, because on the 18th, it still returns 16th, and it should return 17th

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wAWmSFa6yk6 ?

Comment: yeah, but this returns 2 documents, and I only need the last? And if user enters something not in order, this falls apart?

Comment: You can put `$sort` and `$limit` to get only the last one... *And if user enters something not in order* what does it mean?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, with sort I think this will work. Also, does limit returns the first document or the last?

Comment: `$limit`will return first one after sorting...